# Is there a way to count the LIKE results per row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table `jobs` like this:

```
ID | title              | keywords
1  | UI Designer        | HTML, CSS, Photoshop
2  | Web site Designer  | PHP
3  | UI/UX Developer    | CSS, HTML, JavaScript
```

and I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE title LIKE '%UX%' OR title LIKE '%UI%' OR title LIKE '%Developer%' OR keywords LIKE '%HTML%' OR keywords LIKE '%CSS%'
```

I want to sort results by most similarity.

for example for first row (**ID 1**), there is `UI` and `HTML` and `CSS` in the record row. then the number of *CORRECT LIKE* conditions is **3** for first row. same as this calculation, it is **0** for second row and it is **5** for third row.

then I want the result ordered by the number of *CORRECT LIKE* conditions, like this:

```
Results
ID | title              | keywords
3  | UI/UX Developer    | CSS, HTML, JavaScript
1  | UI Designer        | HTML, CSS, Photoshop
```

Then, is there anyway to count the number of similarities per row in query and sort the result like what I describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sum  the matching resul in order by using if

```
SELECT *

FROM jobs
WHERE title LIKE '%UX%' 
OR title LIKE '%UI%' 
OR title LIKE '%Developer%' 
OR keywords LIKE '%HTML%' 
OR keywords LIKE '%CSS%'
ORDER BY (title LIKE '%UX%'+ title LIKE '%UI%'+
       keywords LIKE '%HTML%'+ keywords LIKE '%HTML%') DESC
```

if return 1 or 0  so adding the true result you should obatin  the most matching rows

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing keywords in a string like that.  You should have a separate table.

If -- for some reason such as someone else's really, really, really bad design choices -- you have to deal with this data, then take the delimiters into account.  In MySQL, I would recommend `find_in_set()` for this purpose:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
WHERE title LIKE '%UX%' OR
      title LIKE '%UI%' OR
      title LIKE '%Developer%' OR
      FIND_IN_SET('HTML', REPLACE(keywords, ', ', '')) > 0 OR
      FIND_IN_SET('CSS', REPLACE(keywords, ', ', '')) > 0 
ORDER BY ( (title LIKE '%UX%') +
           (title LIKE '%UI%') +
           (title LIKE '%Developer%') +
           (FIND_IN_SET('HTML', REPLACE(keywords, ', ', '')) > 0) +
           (FIND_IN_SET('CSS', REPLACE(keywords, ', ', '')) > 0)
         ) DESC ;
```

This finds an exact match on the keyword.

You can simplify the `WHERE`, but not the `ORDER BY`, to:

```
WHERE title REGEXP 'UX|UI|Developer' OR
      FIND_IN_SET('HTML', REPLACE(keywords, ', ', '')) > 0 OR
      FIND_IN_SET('CSS', REPLACE(keywords, ', ', '')) > 0
```